# Concatenate ADD operator in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, operators, concatenation

Is it possible to concatenate the OPERATORS(+,-,*,/) then if concatenated do the math.
I have a **`two buttons`** and a **`Sub Procedure`**. When I click **`Button1`** the operator will be using is **`ADD`** and when I click **`Button2`** the operator must be **`MINUS`**. Then I will call my sub procedure to do some stuff there.

Here's my sample code so far:

```
Private Sub SlidePanel(ByVal isSignIn As Boolean, ByVal _operator As String, ByVal _location As Integer)
    Dim pnlMainCurrentLocX As Integer

    If isSignIn = True Then
        _pnlWidth = Me.PanelMain.Location.X
        pnlMainCurrentLocX = (-Me.Size.Width + Me.PanelMain.Location.X)
    Else
        pnlMainCurrentLocX = Me.PanelMain.Location.X
    End If

    Do Until Me.PanelMain.Location.X = pnlMainCurrentLocX
        Me.Refresh()
        Me.PanelMain.Location = New Point(Me.PanelMain.Location.X - 45, Me.PanelMain.Location.Y) '<---- Here I tried concatenating the _operator as string but it gives me error
    Loop

    Do Until Me.pnlUserSettings.Location.X = _location
        Me.Refresh()
        Me.pnlUserSettings.Location = New Point(Me.pnlUserSettings.Location.X - 5, Me.pnlUserSettings.Location.Y) '<----and also here
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SlidePanel(True, "+", 380) '<--- Here, I call my sub procedure
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SlidePanel(False, "-", 415) '<--- Here, I call my sub procedure
End Sub
```

As you can see on my above code how can I pass **`OPERATORS`** then assign it?
Any alternatives and solutions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case a pretty simple loop would suffice:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Messagebox.Show("Division: " & DoCalculations(42.63, 121.23, "+,-,*,/")
End Sub

Private Function DoCalculations(Value1 As Double, Value2 as Double, Operations as String) as Double
   Dim result as Double = Value1
   'Split the operations string into parts at each ,
   'You end up with an array of String, with one element for each operator supplied
   Dim Operators() as String = Strings.Split(Operations, ",")
   'Iterate over each one and perform the respective mathematical operation on the result
   For Each s As String in Operators
      Select Case s
         Case "+": result += Value2
         Case "-": result -= Value2
         Case "*": result *= Value2
         Case "/": result /= Value2
      End Select
   Next
   Return result
End Function
```

A more general and powerful way however is passing a `Delegate`. A method delegate is basically a predesigned method declaration that can be used as a type for a variable (the people who know more about it will probably complain about this definition, but here it's basically used like that).

You declare a delegate function like that:

```
Private Delegate Function MathOperator(Value1 As Double, Value2 as Double) As Double
```

If you have methods that correspond to this declaration (meaning two `Double` parameters and a return value of type `Double`) you can assign that method to a variable of Type MathOperator. You can also use a variable of Type MathOperator as a function parameter. Assign the method you want to use with the `AddressOf` Keyword.

```
'Define your operators
Private Sub Add(Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double) As Double
    Return Value1 + Value2
End Sub
Private Sub Subtract(Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double) As Double
    Return Value1 - Value2
End Sub
Private Sub Multiply(Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double) As Double
    Return Value1 * Value2
End Sub
Private Sub Divide(Value1 As Double, Value2 As Double) As Double
    Return Value1 / Value2
End Sub



Private Function DoCalculation(SomeValue as Double, SomeOtherValue as Double, Operation as MathOperator) As Double
    Dim result as Double = Operation(SomeValue, SomeOtherValue) 'Use the delegate in the same way as any other normal function
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Messagebox.Show("Addition: " & DoCalculation(42.63, 121.23, AddressOf Add)
    Messagebox.Show("Division: " & DoCalculation(42.63, 121.23, AddressOf Divide)
End Sub
```

You can of course also provide a `List(Of MathOperator)` to your calculation function:

```
Private Function DoCalculations(SomeValue as Double, SomeOtherValue as Double, Operations as List(Of MathOperator)) As Double
    Dim result as Double = SomeValue
    'Perform the operation for each delegate supplied
    For Each o as MathOperator in Operations
       Result = o(Result, SomeOtherValue)
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Operations as New List(Of MathOperator)
    Operations.Add(AddressOf Add)
    Operations.Add(AddressOf Multiply)
    Operations.Add(AddressOf Divide)
    Operations.Add(AddressOf Subtract)
    Messagebox.Show("More Stuff: " & DoCalculations(42.63, 121.23, Operations)
End Sub
```

This should solve your problem.
Learning to use delegates can be quite a powerful tool in many situations.

Comment: Thank you Sir!! For your suggestions and broad explanation about delegates.